# Need to replace the namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I need to replace the wrong namespace generated in the output. However, when I transform my XML output into the XSLTFile, the namespace generated in the root element is now correct. But the old namespace appeared in the other elements. 
Thank you in advance for the help.

**INPUT FILE:**

```
<Invoice xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
         xmlns="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" 
         xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:CustomizationID>TR1.2</cbc:CustomizationID>
  <cbc:ProfileID>TEMELFATURA</cbc:ProfileID>
  <cac:InvoicePeriod>
    <cbc:StartDate>2016-02-04</cbc:StartDate>
    <cbc:StartTime>06:00:00</cbc:StartTime>
    <cbc:DurationMeasure unitCode="DAY">15</cbc:DurationMeasure>
  </cac:InvoicePeriod>
</Invoice>
```

**XSLT FILE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='Invoice']">
        <Invoice 
            xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
            xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
            xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 ../xsdrt/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**GENERATED OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
         xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
         xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 ../xsdrt/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd">
  <cbc:UBLVersionID xmlns="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#">2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:CustomizationID xmlns="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#">TR1.2</cbc:CustomizationID>
  <cbc:ProfileID xmlns="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#">TEMELFATURA</cbc:ProfileID>
  <cac:InvoicePeriod xmlns="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#">
    <cbc:StartDate>2016-02-04</cbc:StartDate>
    <cbc:StartTime>06:00:00</cbc:StartTime>
    <cbc:DurationMeasure unitCode="DAY">15</cbc:DurationMeasure>
  </cac:InvoicePeriod>
</Invoice>
```

The elements generates an extra namespace, this is wrong.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
         xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
         xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 ../xsdrt/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd">
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:CustomizationID>TR1.2</cbc:CustomizationID>
  <cbc:ProfileID>TEMELFATURA</cbc:ProfileID>
  <cac:InvoicePeriod>
    <cbc:StartDate>2016-02-04</cbc:StartDate>
    <cbc:StartTime>06:00:00</cbc:StartTime>
    <cbc:DurationMeasure uniedtCode="DAY">15</cbc:DurationMeasure>
  </cac:InvoicePeriod>
</Invoice>
```

Anyways, I already tried many codes in XSLT I saw in the web. But it didn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't actually be any problem with the output you have there. It has extra namespace declarations, but they don't affect the namespaces of any of the elements in your output.

However, if you would like to omit them, you can add one extra `xsl:template` that recreates all of the descendant elements without copying all of the in-scope namespaces on them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='Invoice']">
    <Invoice
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
        xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
        xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 ../xsdrt/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </Invoice>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--   v-------------  this template   -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi @JLRishe, thank you for your feedback. It is already working :)